# Appending .txt file is erasing everything

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class DemoPrint {

    public static void main (String args []) {


        try{

            PrintWriter coolFile = new PrintWriter("c:\\JavaIO\\cool.txt");
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\JavaIO\\cool.txt", true);

            coolFile.println("Why isn't this adding another line?");
            coolFile.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

}
    }
```

So I'm new to programming/java and I'm trying to open this file and append the data and add another line but for some reason the data is just being erased and overwritten with whatever I have in the `coolFile.println("")`.

Can anyone help me out on this? I know its probably a easy fix... I'm learning.. Thank you!

Comment: try removing "FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\JavaIO\\cool.txt", true);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening both a `PrintWriter` and a `FileWriter` on the same file. The two are not related to each other - they are two points of access to the same file (which is something you really shouldn't do).

The opening of the `PrintWriter` has already been done without appending, and therefore, it destroyed all the content of the file. Then you go and open another "view" on it - a `FileWriter`, and it's set to append, but at this point, it no longer has anything to append *to*.

The proper way is to create the `PrintWriter` so that it is *backed* by the `FileWriter`. Not two views on the file - one view that rides on another view.

```
PrintWriter coolFile = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("filename", true ) );
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you that makes sense and I really with my teacher would explain things like this better!